# Makefile target conflict

Tags: c++, makefile

I get conflicts with my Makefile when there are more than 2 targets. I guess the issue is the name of the targets.
So, I have 3 folders, each one containing a Makefile. I want to call all of them. I defined a list (LISTS) containing the list of folders. When I run

```
make before
```

I want that (top level) Makefile runs "make before" in all folders. This code works fine, it does the job

```
LISTS = toto titi tutu

before: $(LISTS)-before
build: $(LISTS)-build

$(LISTS)-before:
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst -before,,$@) before

.PHONY:$(LISTS)-before
```

Now, when I add a new target, it's bugged, for example :

```
LISTS = toto titi tutu

before: $(LISTS)-before
build: $(LISTS)-build

$(LISTS)-before:
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst -before,,$@) before

$(LISTS)-build:
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst -before,,$@) build

.PHONY:$(LISTS)-before $(LISTS)-build
```

When I call still the same command as before (the result should be the same)

```
make before
```

I get :

```
warning: overriding recipe for target `toto'
warning: ignoring old recipe for target `toto'
```

and I can see it runs

```
make build
```

I don't get why it try to run second target, I never called it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I belived `$(LISTS)-before:` is being expanded to `toto titi tutu-before:` which is probably not what you want..

Comment: Yes it's not what I want, I would like `toto-before titi-before tutu-before`. In this case, why it works with only one target ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @anon-mail

The issue was suffix. A working solution is

```
LISTS = toto titi tutu

before: $(LISTS:=-before)
build: $(LISTS:=-build)

$(LISTS:=-before):
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst -before,,$@) before

$(LISTS:=-build):
    $(MAKE) -C $(subst -before,,$@) build

.PHONY:$(LISTS:=-before) $(LISTS:=-build)
```